# Tag suggestion - Language

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I want to suggest a new tag - Language. This would be used by questions that ask about giving robots speech abilities. For instance, this question could use the language tag (https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1476/does-xaiml-have-any-potential-future-in-language-abilities-for-robots).

Comment: It looks like you're trying to self-promote with the Xaiml question you asked, but I'm leaving open the possibility that you're legitimately looking for ways to tailor your work to the needs of the AI community.  Based on this, I could imagine rewriting the question as "what natural language abilities are required by robots (for task X)".  However, I can't see why that would be robotics-related and not [CS theory-related](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks @MarkBooth for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the [natural-language](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language) tag to your question, but sadly it has become apparent that your question is just a thinly veiled advert for your project.

Please read [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) and avoid *self-promotion* in the future. If your question had been a [*practical, answerable question based on an actual problem you face*](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), then this self-promotion would probably not have even been spotted.